# Laravel overridden/appended date attributes aren't serialized in json output

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, php-carbon

I have an Organisation model that has a two data attributes, `allowance_starts_at` and `allowance_ends_at`, when returning this model as JSON I get the following back:

```
allowance_starts_at: "2017-06-01 00:00:00",
allowance_ends_at: "2018-05-31 23:59:59",
```

However I want to override these attributes to set the year to be the current year (or allowance period) so come 2018-06-01 I want the attributes to return:

```
allowance_starts_at: "2018-06-01 00:00:00",
allowance_ends_at: "2019-05-31 23:59:59",
```

To achieve this I'm overriding the attributes in the model like so:

```
public function getAllowanceStartsAtAttribute($value)
{
    $currentYear = Carbon::now()->format('Y');
    $d = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value);
    $d->year($currentYear);

    return $d;
}

public function getAllowanceEndsAtAttribute($value)
{
    $d = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value);

    if ($d->copy()->subYear()->addSecond() != $this->allowance_starts_at) {
        $d->addYear();
    }

    return $d;
}
```

This works and gives me the result I want however, now when I output the model as JSON the Carbon date isn't serialised:

```
allowance_starts_at: {
    date: "2017-01-01 00:00:00.000000",
    timezone_type: 3,
    timezone: "Europe/London"
},
allowance_ends_at: {
    date: "2017-12-31 23:59:59.000000",
    timezone_type: 3,
    timezone: "Europe/London"
},
```

I've also tested this with appended attributes, so instead of overriding an existing attribute I create an appended attribute that just returned `Carbon::now()` and set the appended attribute in the $dates array and this outputs in the same way i.e. not serialized.

Does anyone now how Laravel determines how to output the attributes e.g. as Carbon or as a string?

Does anyone know how I can make this work?

**Update**

---

Thanks Paul. Using a setter mutator gave me the behaviour that I needed. I replaced my overriding methods with:

```
public function setAllowanceStartsAtAttribute($value)
{
    $currentYear = Carbon::now()->format('Y');
    $value->year($currentYear);

    $this->attributes['allowance_starts_at'] = $value;
}

public function setAllowanceEndsAtAttribute($value)
{
    if ($value->copy()->subYear()->addSecond() != $this->attributes['allowance_starts_at']) {
        $value->addYear();
    }

    $this->attributes['allowance_ends_at'] = $value;
}
```

And now I get this output when returning JSON:

```
allowance_starts_at: "2018-06-01 00:00:00",
allowance_ends_at: "2019-05-31 23:59:59",
```

Comment: `$d` is a Carbon object, and Carbon has native handling for output as JSON. If you want output like `"2019-05-31 23:59:59"`, do `return $d->toDateTimeString();` instead of `return $d`.

Comment: Yes, but I need the Carbon instance for when the model is being used internally and the toDateTimeString output only for JSON. Laravel handles this automatically for created_at, updated_at or any other date you set in the $dates array but this only appears to work for dates stored in the database and not for dates being set as attributes on the model itself.

Comment: Looks like overkill but API resources may work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a mutator? Like instead of getAllowanceEndsAtAttribute, make it setAllowanceEndsAtAttribute?